# Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I would like to retrieve the incoming call's phonenumber and do something with it like the do
in http://blog.whitepages.com/2009/02/27/caller-id-by-whitepages-a-new-android-app-that-puts-telemarketers-on-alert/

Could you please help me because I can't find any information about this.
Where do i start and how do i get hold of the phonenumber?

---

Ok so currently my code looks like below. When I place the call the CustomBroadcastReceiver catches it and the log message is printed out. I can retrieve the telephone number from the bundle. But! I can't get hte CustomPhoneStateListener to work. As you can see I have registered my customPhoneState listener to the receiver but the log message never get's printed out from the CustomPhoneStateListener class. What am I my missing here?
Is my thinking correct?

---

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> 
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

---

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

public void onCallStateChange(int state, String incomingNumber){

    Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    Log.v(TAG, incomingNumber);

    switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
            break;
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);

}
```

Comment: I am not getting `incoming_number` for incoming call Device `POCO f1 pi` and receiver is getting called twice

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html). It has an [`onCallStateChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) handler; one of the supplied arguments you'll get is a `String` containing the incoming phone number.

Comment: Could you please provide an example implementation?

Comment: My answer for this question may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136490/androidget-phone-number-of-present-incoming-and-outgoing-call/11182720#11182720)

Comment: I got nothing in the incomingNumber param, what should it be?

Comment: same thing here, not getting phone

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 31.

Answer (score 5):

Your overridden method in `CustomPhoneStateListener` should be called `onCallStateChanged()` (and not `onCallStateChange()`).

This would have been spotted by the Java compiler if you would have had the `@Override` annotation, like you have for `onReceive()`.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks! I have one more question to ask and that is how do i add stuff to the incoming call view?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of that one. Your typo was easier :) However, I think what you are looking for is a Toast. But it will probably not show on the incoming call screen unless your code is a service (and not an activity). But as I said, I haven't gotten this far in Android development myself yet.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are out-od-dated now. There are valid for Android 7 and lower.

For android 9 and higher you have to add another permission in the `Androidmanifest.xml` with the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

without the phone number will be null. For Android 8 I am not sure.

**PhoneStateReciever.java**

```
    package com.incomingcalls;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.e("Incoming Number", "Number is ," + incomingNumber);
            Log.e("State", "State is ," + state);
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Incoming Call State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is -"+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Call Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Call Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**AnroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.incomingcalls">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" /> did you delete this line?