# Can I handle incomeing call in Android SDK 2.0?

Tags: android

I have tried a lot, but I am not able to handle unknown call. Is it possible in Android SDK 2.0? I want to stop calling from unknown number - is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android

Comment: thnx for reply, how i could just re-direct specific numbers in my contacts to my voice-mail.

Comment: just an idea but certainly not the best :
 make a list of number, in which in can add numbers thanks to an edittext for instance. and then make a test on it : if the incoming number is in the list => hang up if not, do your normal stuff

Comment: thnx yaar,i am able to get no. but how can i update state or how i change state