# How to retrieve the contact name from incoming call number?

Tags: android

How to retrieve the contact name from incoming call number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the incoming caller number which you can manage with the help of below reference question:
[Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

So once you have the number, you can use the below code to get the contact name:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME} .....)
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. The application works smoothly when I add READ_CONTACT permission

Comment: Unfortunately, the link has rotted and your answer is useless.  If you can please [edit] to give an answer that doesn't link to an outside source (except as a reference), it will be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER