# Get the name of the caller before programmatically ending the call

Tags: java, android

I have successfully written the code to end calls programmatically. But before the call ends, I want to retrieve the caller's name to log it. How would I retrieve the caller's name? Note, the caller is presumed to be within the contact list.

I've already come across [How to retrieve the contact name from incoming call number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297096/how-to-retrieve-the-contact-name-from-incoming-call-number), and I didn't find the answer satisfying. It has no context, and very little information.

Comment: I did come across that. I was hoping for a different way of doing it. Also, that's not enough information at all.

Comment: That's the type of information you should include in your question. Because to anyone else it appears as though you haven't bothered to search for yourself.

Comment: I shall do it now. Thank you for notifying.