# Android: Firing an activity on a call only for international phone numbers

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, phone-call

I want to launch an activity only when a user calls specific number (e.g.  phone number of a specific country)

From what i read, i understand i can create an intent-filter for android.intent.action.CALL,
but i wonder if i can invoke the application just for certain numbers (just for numbers that belongs to that country, for example). Ideally i will like the user to be able to define this filter himself. so it will not be hard coded in the manifest file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)
You'll need to get the phone number once you receive an incoming call event.
However, please note that unless you override the incoming call intent (which means 
you need yo write your own calling app) your new activity will stay in the background until the phone call app is closed (i.e, until the user reject or end the call).