# how to get number from broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

How do you get a sender number from the broadcast receiver in the form to be able to use that number to send another text back automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get number from broadcast receiver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499414/how-to-get-number-from-broadcast-receiver)

Answer (score 0):

see this link.here you can get incoming number with broadcast receiver.
[Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

here is the link to send sms.
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/