# Pass the values from the BroadcastReceiver to an activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used the following code to get the phone number. I stored the number in a static variable. When I tried to use that variable in another activity, it throws NullPointer Exception.

```
package com.income;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static String info = null;
    static String phonenumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (null == bundle)
            return;
        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver", bundle.toString());
        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver", "State: " + state);
        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            phonenumber = bundle
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            // String d=bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver", "Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);
            info = phonenumber;
        }
        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MissedCall.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: does the log show the number?

Comment: I used the static string in MissedCall activity. String or=IncomingCallReceiver.info; when I print or, it throws nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are getting a `NullPointerException` this means that the bundle is `null` which makes the pone number be null.

I suggest you take a look on how to get the caller's phone number ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)) like how it's done in this post.

**EDIT**

Well what I see is that you are never storing the phone number in the intent that starts the activity, so you will never get the phone number on said activity. Try using `intent1.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);` now that the phone number in `BroadcastReciever` is not null, and retrieve it form `MissedCall.class` using `intent.getExtras("phoneNumber");` where you are trying to get the number.

Comment: thanks, I get the phonenumber, prints in the BroadcastReceiver itself and it get printed.

Comment: while I get it in the another activity, it wont.

Comment: I used that too. But same exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

check your intent.putstring() method