# How to get phone number from an incoming call?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

How do I get the phone number when there is an incoming call in Android?

Comment: you want phone number from recent call history or get when alert incoming call ?

Comment: Please refer to this question: [Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android) And also have a look at this answer too: [how do I get the phone number from incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880508/on-android-how-do-i-get-the-phone-number-from-incoming-call)

Comment: @ChiragPatel from recent incoming call

Comment: there is a similar question [here][1] take a look


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make a `Broadcast receiver` say `ServiceReceiver` assign its action in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add a `PhoneStateListener` to your TelephonyManager, PhoneStateListener having override `onCallStateChanged()` with Incoming number parameter. Thats it.

**ServiceReceiver.Java**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: By using the accepted answer, you will register a new listener with every change of the call state. It will result in multiple onCallStateChanged calls for same event.

Comment: does this require any permission?>

Comment: added this in menifest and it worked<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Every time the broadcast is received, it adds a new listener, so if I get 5 calls, it executes 5 times by the end and so on. Is there a way to keep this from executing as many times as there have been calls?

Comment: Some phones return null `incomingNumber` sometimes. Deal with it.

Comment: is it possible to do this in cordova?

Comment: find no incomingNumber  in case of android P

Comment: to get the mobile number on from incoming calls on android 9 and higher you have to add the CALL_LOG permission and AndroidMinfiest.xml file.

Comment: getting null some times using this Method

Answer (score 6):

Following solution helped me retrieve the incoming and outgoing phone numbers.

**Things to include in manifest** :

1) Permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

2) A broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".AnswerCallBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

**Things to include in BroadcastReceiver class** :

```
    public class AnswerCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            if(arg1.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){

                String state = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Inside Extra state off hook");
                    String number = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Log.e(TAG, "outgoing number : " + number);              
                }       

                else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){   
                    Log.e(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_RINGING");
                    String number = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    Log.e(TAG, "incoming number : " + number);
                }
                else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER?

Comment: EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 4):

you can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
```

Answer (score 4):

This will definitely help you.

Here is an implementation, which will allow you to retrieve the phone number if it is an incoming phone call as incoming Number, and also when the call is FINISHED - note the Handler() code.

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
        // phone ringing
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
        // active
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

        isPhoneCalling = true;
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
        // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
        // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE number");

        if (isPhoneCalling) {

            Handler handler = new Handler();

            //Put in delay because call log is not updated immediately when state changed
            // The dialler takes a little bit of time to write to it 500ms seems to be enough
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // get start of cursor
                      Log.i("CallLogDetailsActivity", "Getting Log activity...");
                        String[] projection = new String[]{Calls.NUMBER};
                        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
                        cur.moveToFirst();
                        String lastCallnumber = cur.getString(0);
                }
            },500);

            isPhoneCalling = false;
        }

    }
}
```

And then add and initialise the listener in your onCreate or onStartCommand code:

```
  PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: matter of fact, call log is not updated at all during call. Only after call is finished

Answer (score 2):

If you are using InCallService and you have a Call object then you can quickly get the incoming phone number by using the following code

```
if (call.getDetails().getGatewayInfo()!=null){

number=call.getDetails().getGatewayInfo().getOriginalAddress().getSchemeSpecificPart();}

else {  
number=mainCall.getDetails().getHandle().getSchemeSpecificPart();}
```

Here the call is the object from `android.telecom.Call`package and the 'number' is a string type variable.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are right, but, don't forget about permissions
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

NOTE, starting form `Android 9` to read incoming call number you have to request this permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />`

Answer (score 0):

From Android 9 explicitly ask for two runtime permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Now inside `onReceive` we can extract phone number from intent

```
String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

But the catch is here:
`onReceive` method is called twice for each state, one EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER  with blank, and other populated with the phone number.
So if you want to extract phone number you must get the correct value you can do this, just return which contain null ..

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 if(!intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER))
            return;
   //....Further TODO
}
```