# how do i retrieve the incoming phone call's number and send a sms while reject the call?

Tags: android, android-intent

when someone make a call then if i reject or drop the call,my application send an automatic reply to the caller.But i fetch a problem,when i reject the call the AVD shows a message- "Unfortunately Autoreply2Caller is Stop " .Please,help .Here is my source code:
    package bd.com.example.autoreply2caller;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReplyToCaller extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received: " + intent.getAction(),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            // extract the SMS
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] chunks = null;
            String number = "";
            String text = "";

            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                chunks = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    chunks[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    text += chunks[i].getMessageBody();
                    number = chunks[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "SMS Received: from: " + number + " Message Body: " + text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // send an automatic reply
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null,
                    "I am busy right now. I'll call you later.", null, null);

        }

        // reply to the caller
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Phone is ringing

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // Call received

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // Call Dropped or rejected
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


            // send an automatic reply
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null,
                    "I am busy right now. I'll call you later.", null, null);

        }

    }
}
```

And the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bd.com.example.autoreply2caller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="ReplyToCaller">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>


11-18 20:05:30.543: D/AndroidRuntime(3311): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-18 20:05:30.543: D/AndroidRuntime(3311): CheckJNI is ON
11-18 20:05:30.613: D/dalvikvm(3311): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-18 20:05:30.623: D/dalvikvm(3311): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-18 20:05:30.709: D/dalvikvm(3311): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-18 20:05:30.709: D/dalvikvm(3311): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-18 20:05:31.899: D/AndroidRuntime(3311): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-18 20:05:31.963: I/ActivityManager(1022): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=bd.com.example.autoreply2caller/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 3311
11-18 20:05:31.963: W/WindowManager(1022): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21030
11-18 20:05:32.093: D/AndroidRuntime(3311): Shutting down VM
11-18 20:05:32.093: D/dalvikvm(798): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 20:05:32.103: I/ActivityManager(1022): Start proc bd.com.example.autoreply2caller for activity bd.com.example.autoreply2caller/.MainActivity: pid=3321 uid=10053 gids={1028}
11-18 20:05:32.193: D/dalvikvm(3321): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-18 20:05:32.247: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:32.293: D/dalvikvm(3321): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-18 20:05:32.303: D/dalvikvm(3311): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 479K/2048K, paused 4ms+36ms, total 163ms
11-18 20:05:32.303: D/jdwp(3311): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-18 20:05:32.303: D/dalvikvm(3311): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-18 20:05:32.393: D/dalvikvm(798): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 6% free 5935K/6275K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 272ms
11-18 20:05:32.393: D/dalvikvm(798): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 20:05:32.413: E/Trace(3321): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-18 20:05:32.533: D/dalvikvm(798): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 5935K/6275K, paused 45ms+5ms, total 139ms
11-18 20:05:32.533: D/dalvikvm(798): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 20:05:32.683: D/dalvikvm(1022): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 20:05:32.693: D/dalvikvm(798): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 5935K/6275K, paused 67ms+3ms, total 157ms
11-18 20:05:32.903: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:33.423: D/dalvikvm(1022): GC_EXPLICIT freed 484K, 20% free 9202K/11399K, paused 15ms+25ms, total 738ms
11-18 20:05:33.523: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:33.793: D/gralloc_goldfish(3321): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-18 20:05:33.903: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:33.903: I/ActivityManager(1022): Displayed bd.com.example.autoreply2caller/.MainActivity: +1s854ms
11-18 20:05:33.983: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:35.492: D/CallNotifier(1119): RINGING... (new)
11-18 20:05:35.492: D/CallNotifier(1119): onNewRingingConnection(): state = RINGING, conn = {  incoming: true state: INCOMING post dial state: NOT_STARTED }
11-18 20:05:35.502: D/CallNotifier(1119): SignalInfoTonePlayer.run(toneId = 98)...
11-18 20:05:35.552: D/PhoneNumberUtils(1119): System property doesn't provide any emergency numbers. Use embedded logic for determining ones.
11-18 20:05:35.602: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < expand icons ALERTS* ticker system_info back home recent clock >
11-18 20:05:35.642: D/AccelerometerListener(1119): enable(false)
11-18 20:05:35.862: D/CallNotifier(1119): showIncomingCall()...  phone state = RINGING
11-18 20:05:35.962: D/dalvikvm(1191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 334K, 9% free 6894K/7495K, paused 16ms+6ms, total 253ms
11-18 20:05:36.063: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): addNotification score=20
11-18 20:05:36.342: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): Notification has fullScreenIntent; sending fullScreenIntent
11-18 20:05:36.342: I/ActivityManager(1022): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10840000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen u=0} from pid -1
11-18 20:05:36.392: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:36.392: W/WindowManager(1022): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21030
11-18 20:05:36.412: E/WVMExtractor(800): Failed to open libwvm.so
11-18 20:05:36.543: I/Choreographer(1084): Skipped 156 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:36.692: D/Ringtone(1119): Successfully created local player
11-18 20:05:36.692: I/AudioService(1022):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls
11-18 20:05:36.722: D/AudioHardwareInterface(800): setMode(RINGTONE)
11-18 20:05:36.772: I/Choreographer(1084): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:36.812: D/AudioSink(800): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
11-18 20:05:36.822: I/Choreographer(1084): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:36.912: D/InCallScreen(1119): onNewIntent: intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10c40000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen }, phone state = RINGING
11-18 20:05:36.912: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < EXPAND* icons ALERTS ticker system_info back home recent clock >
11-18 20:05:37.063: D/InCallTouchUi(1119): showIncomingCallWidget(). widget visibility: 8
11-18 20:05:37.105: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.105: I/Choreographer(1084): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.122: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < EXPAND icons ALERTS ticker system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT* clock >
11-18 20:05:37.162: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 144 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.326: I/Choreographer(1084): Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.692: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 237 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.732: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:37.862: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:38.732: D/InCallTouchUi(1119): showIncomingCallWidget(). widget visibility: 0
11-18 20:05:38.742: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 725 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:38.912: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:39.142: D/dalvikvm(1310): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 20:05:39.172: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 249 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:39.462: D/dalvikvm(1310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 296K, 12% free 8404K/9479K, paused 4ms+54ms, total 325ms
11-18 20:05:39.692: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 317 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:39.842: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:40.062: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 143 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:40.372: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 205 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:40.672: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 193 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:40.902: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 153 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:41.192: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 187 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:41.304: D/dalvikvm(1119): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 9% free 7589K/8327K, paused 47ms+11ms, total 189ms
11-18 20:05:41.432: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 156 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:41.672: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 157 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:41.972: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 191 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:42.292: D/PhoneUtils(1119): hangup(): hanging up ringing call
11-18 20:05:42.292: D/PhoneUtils(1119): hangupRingingCall(): regular incoming call: hangup()
11-18 20:05:42.292: D/PhoneUtils(1119): - hangup(Call): regular hangup()...
11-18 20:05:42.332: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 235 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:42.622: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 225 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:42.732: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:42.852: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:43.122: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < EXPAND icons alerts* ticker system_info BACK HOME RECENT clock >
11-18 20:05:43.174: D/AndroidRuntime(3321): Shutting down VM
11-18 20:05:43.174: W/dalvikvm(3321): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3de7288)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver bd.com.example.autoreply2caller.ReplyToCaller: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:77)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:79)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at bd.com.example.autoreply2caller.ReplyToCaller.onReceive(ReplyToCaller.java:74)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
11-18 20:05:43.192: E/AndroidRuntime(3321):     ... 10 more
11-18 20:05:43.202: D/AccelerometerListener(1119): enable(false)
11-18 20:05:43.252: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < expand* icons alerts ticker system_info BACK HOME RECENT clock >
11-18 20:05:43.282: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 273 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:43.613: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:43.922: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:43.962: D/InCallTouchUi(1119): hideIncomingCallWidget()
11-18 20:05:43.972: D/PhoneStatusBar(1084): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back* home* recent* clock >
11-18 20:05:43.972: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 441 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:44.202: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:44.542: D/CallNotifier(1119): onDisconnect: cause = INCOMING_REJECTED, incoming = true, date = 1353247535489
11-18 20:05:44.542: D/CallNotifier(1119): SignalInfoTonePlayer.run(toneId = 98)...
11-18 20:05:44.602: D/AudioHardwareInterface(800): setMode(NORMAL)
11-18 20:05:44.642: I/AudioService(1022):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls
11-18 20:05:44.692: I/PowerManagerService(1022): clearUserActivity for 10000ms from now
11-18 20:05:44.702: D/PhoneNumberUtils(1119): System property doesn't provide any emergency numbers. Use embedded logic for determining ones.
11-18 20:05:44.713: I/ActivityManager(1022): moveTaskToBack: 6
11-18 20:05:45.002: W/WindowManager(1022): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21035
11-18 20:05:45.092: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 723 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:45.182: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:45.443: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 228 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:45.573: I/Choreographer(1119): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:45.747: D/InCallTouchUi(1119): - triggerPing: InCallScreen no longer in foreground; ignoring...
11-18 20:05:46.454: W/ActivityManager(1022): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-18 20:05:50.532: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 20:05:55.350: W/ActivityManager(1022): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{b471e7b0 bd.com.example.autoreply2caller/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: Please post a logcat of the crash. then we can identify the issue.

Comment: i added the logcat message below manifest code...please help

Answer (score 0):

For listening to phone state use the `PhoneStateListener` see : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154533/803225)

Try `smsMessages[n].getDisplayOriginatingAddress()`

I always pull the address from the SMS like so:

```
Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
smsMessages = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++)
{
    smsMessages[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    JLog.v("Reciever: SMS :-\r\n ========== \r\n "
            + smsMessages[n].getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "\r\n "
            + smsMessages[n].getServiceCenterAddress() + "\r\n "
            + smsMessages[n].getDisplayMessageBody() 
            + "\r\n========");
}
```

Also what you may have to do when resending a sms is make the sure the number is formatted! Logging this stuff out reallllly helps!

The outgoing phone number needs to look like `4412345123456` or any other valid number.

[PhoneNumberUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) has formatting methods for you.

Comment: my problem is here : else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // Call Dropped or rejected
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


            // send an automatic reply
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null,
                    "I am busy right now. I'll call you later.", null, null);

        }