# country code of incoming calls in android

Tags: android, country-codes

I've just built an application that detecting incoming calls. I see that in some phones(or in different version of android) incoming call number has country code, some incoming numbers has not. Is there a way to get incoming calls with country codes in any android phone and in any version of android?

I use broadcast receiver and PhoneStateListener, I get the parameter of incomingNumber at onCallStateChanged. So I didn't use telephonymanager.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER (In fact I don't what exactly EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code-snippet that you can use in your BroadcastReceiver to extract the country-code using *libphonenumber* library.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
    // get phone number from bundle
    String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    // get country-code from the phoneNumber
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    try {
       PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
       if (phoneUtil.isValidNumber(numberProto)) {
          log.d("TAG", "Country Code: " + numberProto.getCountryCode());
       } else {
          log.d("TAG", "Invalid number format: " + phoneNumber);
       }
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Unable to parse phoneNumber " + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to use : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.9.2 download JAR file and use in android

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done with libphonenumber library https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 0):

`EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER` holds number **entered** by user

> A String holding the phone number originally entered in
>   ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, or the actual number to call in a
>   ACTION_CALL.

via http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER

Also, have you seen: [How to get phone number from an incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call) ?