# how to receive an incoming call in android using TelephonyManager class?

Tags: android

can anyone please suggest me, that what should I do to receive an incoming call through android code than do some stuff and end that call?
I've been searching it from a long and haven't got any thing related...

Comment: if you mean pick up the phone and then end call, then I doubt you can do it. You can at most detect state changes of phone call.

Comment: I am not pretty sure . I think we can do that . I have developed one app in which I have detected the incoming call and rejected it through code. But I am not sure about accepting the call , I will try out and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You have to make BroadcastReceiver for receiving an incoming call.
Refer to hotveryspicy's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call) Link.