# How to use call log for copy incoming number in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I just want to copy the incoming number and paste it to a text box. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to tell a bit about what you have investigated to do that.

Comment: You have to register one Broadcast Receiver to receive incoming number and from receiver you can get number.see this link it may helpful                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor to get any call log information you want.

```
String[] projection = {android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.DATE};
final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                "type = " + CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC" + " LIMIT 200");
```

The cursor will result the number and time of call.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                try {

                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                    // Do anything with number and name
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
```