# How to override contact data?

Tags: android, addressbook, incoming-call

Writing my own kind of contact manager (with some extras) I want to override or integrate the android contacts.

For example: If an incoming call comes, there should be the possibility to show my own contact data for the incoming phone number.

(I do not want to copy my data into the android address book.)

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will get the incoming phone number (refer -  [How to get phone number from an incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call) ). from that you add the name of number and change the incoming call screen like truecaller.