# Get phone number during calling state in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get phone number during calling state in android with two ways. 
Here are the codes:
The first way is

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        mPhoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}
```

And the second way is

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{
        //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
        Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
        public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            Log.d("Number", incomingNumber);
        }
}
```

But, i can't get phone number with 2 ways. When I executed these codes, `mPhoneNumber` is null in the first way and also `incomingNumber` is null in the second way.
I followed sample codes from 
[How to get phone number from an incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call).
Please help me what I got wrong?