# Display Custom Activity for Incoming Call dependent on Phone Number [Android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I am building an app that shows a custom activity only if the phone number is a list of phone numbers.

I understand that I would be creating a

```
BroadcastReceiver
```

and

```
PhoneStateListener
```

Could someone let me know how / where I should check the phone number and either display a **custom activity** or the **standard** / **default activity** ?

Thanks!

Comment: See first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call. That's how you get the incoming call's number, but I'm not sure if you can show a custom activity

Comment: Thanks for the phone number fetcher. I hope to be able to show a custom activity :)