# Android draw view on incoming call

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am trying to show a view over incoming phone call , Like true caller. Please let me know how i can implement that.

I am trying to use this code: But it is showing me some error

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    if (SysUtils.isGteAndroid4()) {
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size;
    } else {
        return new Point(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Mind posting the error?

Comment: Sorry man , Right now i am not on my development system . Do you have any refrence please  let me know . I need a full tutorial for that.If you can guide me for that ten it will be helpfull

Comment: Here is how you can view [Incoming Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call)