# Marshmallow broadcasts receiver without runtime permission

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Why is my broadcast receiver not working? What did I do wrong and how to solve?

There are similar questions:
[Broadcast Receivers not working in Android 6.0 Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036523/broadcast-receivers-not-working-in-android-6-0-marshmallow)
[Android Broadcast receiver for call not working? (Marshmallow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902972/android-broadcast-receiver-for-call-not-working-marshmallow)

These questions are related to runtime permission issue. In my case, it is not permission issue (I guess), because I am not using any permission related service. I just want to create a simple Broadcast Receiver - sending a message and showing the message as Toast.

> min SDK : 21
>   max SDK : 25
>   test device : Note 4 (N910U) running 6.0.1

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name="package.MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "foo";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getExtras().getString("mgs"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //MyBroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        //IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        //intentFilter.addAction("MyBroadcastReceiver");
        //registerReceiver(br, intentFilter); // local BR

        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_send:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("MyBroadcastReceiver");
                intent.putExtra("mgs","Just a test message");
                this.sendBroadcast(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does app crash or you just don't see toast?

Comment: @Marat I don't see the Toast

Comment: Did you check with `Log` if the `onReceive` method has been called? Also, in manifest, why do you have receiver name as `package.MyBroadcastReceiver` but not `.MyBroadcastReceiver`?