# How to know why receiver is not calling class and onReceive not executing

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Im building an android app to detect incoming calls. It use to work a year ago, but something i´ve change has mess it up.

I reduce the code to the basis to debug, but i cant still make a Toast Notification apear when phone is reciving calls.

Has it been some major change to the permissions with reading phone state? I´ve made the modification for androdi 9 adding the ReadCallLog permision, but nothing seems to change...

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

MyPhoneReceiver.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Eureka!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865079/6571092) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38914288/6571092). You need to approve the runtime permission READ_PHONE_STATE.