# Is it possible to Catch incoming Phone Number? Using Cordova

Tags: android, iphone, web-services, cordova, cordova-plugins

This is primarily for my Work place so having an app running all the time is not an issue.

The question How do i attach a hook to activate the App or background process when a call is made, and can it retrieve the phone number?

All the App has to do is send a request with the phone number to a server in-house

The reason for the question:

I am toying with the idea of creating a Support Service module which can give the Service worker a better grasp of the problem at hand.

Consider this:

> 1. Customer calls the company's support line
> 2. Service worker picks up phone
> 3. The computer looks up the Customers phone number on the Company's database and gives the Service Worker every detail they have on the customer ( Issues created, Website, Basic Info )

The biggest problem i can see is how do i Catch the number coming from the phone?

Looking up a customer via their phone number is not the issue.

Alternatively the Service worker will have to manually enter the phone number, but would be a nice feature to do it automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get phone number from an incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You will need a BroadcastReceiver and have to override

```
@Override
protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
{
    //
}
```

---

Also insert permissions in Manifest.xml . If you want compatibility over oreo use runtime permissions for those permissions