# Android get current incoming phone number

Tags: android, call, phone-number, telephonymanager

We want to get the current incoming phone number.
The user may answer the phone call first. Then he will open the app and try to fill a form. We want to detect the current incoming phone number automatically.
We tried with [How to get phone number from an incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call)
But it will detect only state changes.
Are they any solution to this or do we have to create foreground or background service for this?