# Save incoming number in a variable to use in the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, numbers, broadcastreceiver

I was looking at the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Activity` and I didn´t find a right mode to use the incoming number that I have from the `BroadcastReceiver` in my `Activity`. This is the code that I use to intercept the incoming number and visualize in a `Toast`:

```
    public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
     String ophoneNumber;
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent incoming) {  
   Bundle bundle = incoming.getExtras();   
     ophoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");  
     Toast.makeText(context, ophoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
}
```

Manifest part:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver">     
       <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />   
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My problem is that I have to use the incoming number in an `Activity` that is running, so I have also read about the possibility to put the `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Activity` like this:

```
public void monitorIncomingCalls(){
          INcall = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                     final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  
                 if(intent.getAction().equalsTelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
                inphoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 
                            }
                       };
     registerReceiver(INcall, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER));
                                                     }
```

But with this I don´t have nothing in the inphoneNumber variable, I think because I can´t register correctly the `BroadcastReceiver` because I miss the permission.
I didn´t find in the web an example that is working for what I want, that is basically put in a variable in my `Activity` the number that is calling me.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

Check out this link to save the incoming number.

1. Extend PhoneStateListener
2. Extend BroadCastReceiver
3. Display the toast.