# Get phone number of present incoming and outgoing call

Tags: android, phone-number

I am making an app in which I have to retrieve the phone number and I am able to retrieve it but my problem is that I am getting **phone number** of **last call** rather than **present call**.My code is as follows:

```
projection = new String[]{Calls.NUMBER};
cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
cur.requery();
numberColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER);
cur.requery();
cur.requery();
cur.requery();
cur.requery();
cur.moveToLast();
s = cur.getString(numberColumn);
String pathname = "/sdcard/" + s + ".amr";
```

Comment: you need to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android

Comment: sandy,I have seen that but can you please tell where to add code snipet in my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As suggested by Krutix, the call LOG, is a LOG of finished phone calls which is written to by the dialer app after a call is finished. As such you will not find which number is currently dialing in the content provider.

Here is an implementation which will allow you to retrieve the phone number if it is an incoming phone call as incomingNumber and also when the call is FINISHED - note the Handler() code.

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
            // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE number");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Handler handler = new Handler();

                //Put in delay because call log is not updated immediately when state changed
                // The dialler takes a little bit of time to write to it 500ms seems to be enough
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // get start of cursor
                          Log.i("CallLogDetailsActivity", "Getting Log activity...");
                            String[] projection = new String[]{Calls.NUMBER};
                            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
                            cur.moveToFirst();
                            String lastCallnumber = cur.getString(0);
                    }
                },500);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And then add and initialise the listener in your onCreate or onStartCommand code:

```
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Compile time error: The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}?

Comment: solved it by specifying a field private Context context; and context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE + " desc");

Reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165609/sms-logger-method-getcontentresolver-is-undefined-for-the-type?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Do not store a private field of type Context. Instead, use WeakReference<Context> someName, and, whenever you need to use a context, call someName.get() -- this will return a context. In the place where you store a context, just create the weakReference with new WeakReference<>(context);

Answer (score 1):

please modify your query with

```
 cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
  cur.moveToFirst();
  s = cur.getString(numberColumn);
```

it will give last call's phone number and there is no need requery so many times

Comment: Still i am getting previous number

Comment: using my code you can get data after your call is finished and as you want that info when call is ringing or on hold you have to use listener and receiver

Comment: Can you please help with some example

Comment: what u exactly want in your code coz sandy already post link that code help you

Comment: what you exactly want I cant understand?

Comment: i want to get number of call when we make a call or when call is recieved