# SMS Logger: method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'am begginer in android programming and I'am trying to create app that is logging sms's to a file.
Iam having a problem with "The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type SMSObserver" and i dont know why...

Here is the code:

```js
public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver
{
SMSLogger smsLogger;

public SMSObserver(SMSLogger smsLogger) {
    super(new Handler());
    this.smsLogger = smsLogger;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    querySMS();
}

protected void querySMS() {
    Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToNext();
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
    String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
    String time = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
    String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
    String out = "";
    if (protocol == null)
        out = "Sending to "+add + ".Time:"+time +" - "+body;
    else out = "Receive from "+add + ".Time:"+time +" - "+body;
    /*logging action HERE...*/
}
}
```

and the imports:

```
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call that method only on Context object. 
Try this:

```
public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver
{
SMSLogger smsLogger;
Context context;

public SMSObserver(SMSLogger smsLogger, Context c) {
    super(new Handler());
    context = c;
    this.smsLogger = smsLogger;
}

protected void querySMS() {
    Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend Application to keep hold of a context and access it statically Or you can pass function call to each library function in ContentResolver. Currently you do not have Context reference so you can not call getContentResolver() here.