# Android Incoming Call event

Tags: android

I want to make an onCall event, I allready know that theres no such method but basicly what i want to do:

when an incoming call is recived, Popup Toast (or anything else)

any kind of tutorials or example code would help.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `PhoneStateListener` which has overrided method `onCallStateChanged` You can use 3 states over there

[Example link](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/)

Answer (score 3):

For that you need to use `PhoneStateListener`

see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1853220/1289716) you will get idea how to use.

Also try this [demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html)

Comment: Not really an answer. 2nd sentence merely refers to the other Q and 3rd to the page which is down by now.