# While running an application if any call comes how to handle and which methods called?

Tags: android

While running an application if any call comes how to handle and which method is called?

Comment: The question is very vague. You need to add some detail to it, and be explicit about what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and what has or has not worked. People here will definitely try to help, but the more you give them the easier it will be for them, and the higher chances you'll have of receiving an answer.

Comment: how to handle - what?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251694/android-incoming-call-event) question, perhaps it is useful. It makes use of the `PhoneStateListener`.