# How to get outgoing phone number when the call is made in Android Pie in PhoneStateListener?

Tags: java, android

```
private final class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String outgoingnumber) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I tried using this class and override this method, but in android pie "outgoingnumber" is received as blank string

Comment: Tried this?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19005642/4636715 . If no help, please share what you've tried.

Comment: already did this way,  but not getting number in PHONESTATELISTENER's method.

Comment: Check this thread :https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/abh353/guidelines_for_call_recorder_apps_for_googles_jan/