# Detect incoming call with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to capture the incoming call event using Phonegap. I want to detect if there is any event of incoming call occured and pause my media files from playing. So far I have found about **startcallbutton** & **endcallbutton**events. But I want to detect the call from the moment of ringing. Searched in Phonegap google group but not finding any solution that could work for me.

I'm new to phonegap. Am I missing something? **Can anyone please help me that how can I detect the incoming call and take action after that?** Is that solution device independent?

Comment: Use this http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-get-devices-phone-number-using.html reference for detect incoming call.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this plugin solves it for you? https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap

Do note that you will always require a plugin, since Phonegap/Cordova has no API to detect calls. And plugins are platform specific, but since you tagged your question Android I suppose you only target Android?

Answer (score 0):

as I as I could remember, you should set up intent filter for calling event, and get action from that event...and handle it.

reading the following material will help you to understand~

[Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE

[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/detecting-an-incoming-call-coming-to-an-android-device)