# How to say a caller name not caller number?

Tags: android

this is my main activity code.. all is good but it say caller number not the caller name.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    tts.speak(incomingNumber+" calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Ringing : "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone in a call or call picked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"phone is neither ringing nor in a call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926776/android-say-caller-name

Answer (score 0):

> all is good but it say caller number not the caller name

You need to look up the phonenumber in user contacts to see if you got any record matching.

Comment: can you share the code lines for that. that it check for the contact if contact available in contact list else it say the number when contact not available in contact list