# Trigger event based on the phone number called

Tags: android

Essentially I would like to have an Android app that will trigger an event only if a phone call is placed to a certain phone number. All other phone calls would be ignored.

This would be involved in a limited use case, and the appropriate permissions/warnings would be given so that the user is informed of what is going on.

Is this something that is possible within the Android ecosystem?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android

Comment: Darnit, my pre-searching failed. Thank you for the link.