# Android :For a incoming call number how i search the contact list And Find the contact Name

Tags: android

HERE MY CODE .. For any incoming number i try to find the caller name and return the name where this method invoke .. pls help

```
public  String getName(String number){

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));
    String name = "Incoming call from";

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri,new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

    try{
        if(contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount()>0 ){
            contactLookup.moveToNext();
            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

Here the method invoke part

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    String s = incomingNumber;
    String ss = getName(s);
    if(state== TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING ){
        tts.speak(ss +" calling please answer ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Ringing : " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use PhoneStateListener. It has an onCallStateChanged handler; one of the supplied arguments you'll get is a String containing the incoming phone number.

Check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android) for more details about implementation.

Comment: Check again i also add where the method invoked @geek90

Comment: Can you explain what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace, looks like there is an issue with your getName method.

Comment: 12-23 06:41:59.727    6812-6812/com.example.jahid.firsttalk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jahid.firsttalk, PID: 6812
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/, calling 

user: com.example.jahid.firsttalk, calling package:com.example.jahid.firsttalk
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)

Comment: at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
            at com.example.jahid.firsttalk.MainActivity.getName(MainActivity.java:89)
            at com.example.jahid.firsttalk.MainActivity$1.onCallStateChanged(MainActivity.java:39)
            at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: i think problem may be there ------   Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri,new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);  Error :-com.example.jahid.firsttalk.MainActivity.getName(MainActivity.java:89) at